# Conjectured characterization of a set relative to a convex cone

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a convex cone (i.e., for all $x,y\in X$ and $\alpha,\beta\geq 0$ scalars, $\alpha x+\beta y\in X$). Define the set $$A(x)=\{a:x+a\in X \wedge x-a\in X\}.$$

Then, $A(x)=(-x+X)\cap (x+(-X))$, where this set addition has the standard definition. Is this claim true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true. It's simply due to the basic properties of set addition. That is, since $x + a \in X \Leftrightarrow a \in -x + X$ and $x-a \in X \Leftrightarrow a\in x + (-X)$, we have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
A(x) &= \{a:x+a\in X \wedge x-a\in X\} \\
     &= \{a:a \in -x + X \wedge a\in x + (-X)\} \\
     &= (-x+X)\cap (x+(-X))
\end{aligned}
$$
The fact that $X$ is a convex cone is irrelevant here.